# Can I update an object inside an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, vector

So I created an object and then added it into an array

```
Class Item{
...
};

Class Machine{
   void setQuantity(int i);
};

Machine::Machine(){
   Item items[5];

   items[0] = a(int q);
}
```

I defined the setQuantity() and then tried to setQuantity later in the code, with

```
items[0].setQuantity(items[0].getQuantity() + 1);
```

but the quantity of a didn't update. Is it because I can't update a property of an item in an array or why can't the quantity change?

I'm thinking of changing the array into a vector, but I'm wondering if the problem is with the array or not. If it isn't then changing it into a vector won't matter does it?

Thanks in advance!

```
int Item::getQuantity(){
     return quantity; 
}  
void Item::setQuantity(int q){
     quantity = q; 
}

items[i].setQuantity(items[i].getQuantity + 1);
```

Comment: for sure the problem isn't with the array, what you'd like to do is perfectly feasible; can you please post the detailed code of ```setQuantity``` and ```getQuantity``` functions?

Comment: `int Item::getQuantity(){
    return quantity;
}

void Item::setQuantity(int q){
    quantity = q;
}`

Comment: also I changed in a for loop, so it's more like 

`items[i].setQuantity(items[i].getQuantity + 1);`

Comment: Does it matter that it was called in a different function?

Comment: Please edit your code into the question. Comments don't handle code too well, and are subject to being deleted. Edit your question with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are declaring a variable inside a function call `a()`, which is, based on the code listed, undefined.

`int q` is the syntax for a variable declaration, but no value has been defined for `q`.

For each of the 5 `items` that you create, the default constructor of the class `Item` is called.

If you want to assign a value to `items[0]` you can (and probably should), for example, implement an assignment operator and a copy constructor in `Item`. Or you could store pointers to `Item` in the array instead of the objects themselves, and then use `items[0] = new Item(...)` to assign the items.

Comment: `Item::Item(int x, string n, int p, int q, string d){
    num = x;
    name = n;
    price = p;
    quantity = q;
    desc = d;
}
` 
I defined it like this, and wrote complete codes. The one in the question is the simplified version. But true, I should try pointers. Thanks a lot!